# How to create mongoose schema with time series data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying a schema for time series data. But I am not able to save column values data. So I want to define values clearly what it should be not just empty object. So I looked on the net and I got info about time series on mongo db here [link](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb). But I am not able to create the perfect schema.

I really need someone's help to solve this problem. I tried many things and only following way I came to know about.

I am trying to insert code like following:

```
const symbol = 'WLTW';
const date = '2016-01-05 00:00:00';
const open = 123.43;
const close = 125.839996;
const low = 122.309998;
const high = 126.25;
const volume = 2163600.0;
const month = 1;
const day = 5;

const stock = new Stock({
  date,
  symbol,
  values: { [month]: { [day]: { open, close, low, high, volume } } }
});

stock
  .save()
  .then(res => `Result = ${res}`)
  .catch(e => `Error = ${e}`);


const stockSchema = new Schema({
  symbol: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: { type: Date },
  values: {
    month: {
      day: {
        open: { type: Number },
        close: { type: Number },
        low: { type: Number },
        high: { type: Number },
        volume: { type: Number }
       }
    }
  }
});
```

Actual how I am getting:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c40d7b655f7836a7fd4e3cf"
    },
    "date": {
        "$date": "2016-01-04T18:30:00.000Z"
    },
    "symbol": "WLTW",
    "__v": 0
}
```

But if I make a change in my schema where I give  `values: {}` than I get correct data in my db:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c40d2e6a73ca369f61de9a3"
    },
    "date": {
        "$date": "2016-01-04T18:30:00.000Z"
    },
    "symbol": "WLTW",
    "values": {
        "1": {
            "5": {
                "open": 123.43,
                "close": 125.839996,
                "low": 122.309998,
                "high": 126.25,
                "volume": 2163600
            }
        }
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading several articles and searching for many days. I came to know that best practice is to keep any dynamic data out of the field names.

So I decided that and updated my schema such that now field names are not dynamic data.

```
const stockSchema = new Schema({
  symbol: { type: String, required: true },
  date: { type: Date, required: true },
  values: {
    month: {
      value: { type: Number, required: true },
      day: {
        value: { type: Number, required: true },
        open: { type: Number },
        close: { type: Number },
        low: { type: Number },
        high: { type: Number },
        volume: { type: Number }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

And then the table view will be:

```
{
    "_id": "id",
    "symbol": "symbol",
    "date": "date",
    "month": "values.month.value",
    "day": "values.month.day.value",
    "open": "values.month.day.open",
    "close": "values.month.day.close",
    "low": "values.month.day.low",
    "high": "values.month.day.high",
    "volume": "values.month.day.volume"
}
```